# How to display files uploaded using carrierwave, fog and local storage with rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, image-uploading, fog

I am using carrierwave with fog to create a simple image uploading process on my server. 
The goal is to have images stored in my server in this folder :

```
/opt/myapp/uploads/
```

I have configured carrierwave and fog with that parameters and the upload is working very well :

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|

  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'Local', 
    :local_root             => '/opt/myapp/' 
  }
  config.fog_public     = false               
  config.fog_directory  = 'uploads/' 

  config.storage = :fog
  config.asset_host = proc do |file|
    '/opt/myapp/uploads/'
  end
end
```

When I upload an image I can see that it is stored in the corresponding folder. But how can I display them in my web pages ? 
The generated url is

```
http://localhost:3000/opt/myapp/uploads/<path-to-my-image>.png
```

So my application tries to get images from an opt/ folder in my rails application directory, but how could I tell it to retrieve them from the server filesystem instead ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok,that was easy to do :

First add a route for the corresponding urls :

```
match '/opt/myapp/uploads/:file_name' => 'files#serve'
```

The create a FilesController with a serve method :

```
class FilesController < ApplicationController

  def serve
    before_filter :authenticate_user! #used with Devise to protect the access to the images
    path = "/opt/myapp/uploads/#{params[:file_name]}.png"

    send_file( path,
      :disposition => 'inline',
      :type => 'image/png',
      :x_sendfile => true )
  end
end
```

Then I needed to add this line in my development.rb and production.rb configuration files :

```
config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Accel-Redirect" #to use with Thin and Nginx
```